# Import threshold_yen and threshold_isodata from skimage.filter

Tags: python, import, threshold, scikit-image

I am working with different threshold algorithms from SKimage, and when I go to import certain packages I get an error, but have no problem with others. For example:

`from skimage.filter import threshold_adaptive, threshold_isodata` 
returns the traceback: 
`ImportError: cannot import name threshold_isodata`. I am using python 2.7, and following the documentation found here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filter.html#skimage.filter.threshold_isodata

Specifically, I'm hoping to use threshold_isodata and threshold_yen. Does anybody have suggestions for how to solve this error? Alternatively, are there other packages that use the same algorithm?

Comment: Which version are you using? `threshold_yen` was released in v0.9 and `threshold_isodata` is only available in the master repo (i.e. not officially released). The website defaults to the development docs. For official releases the doc path looks like http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/

Comment: I'm running windows, so I'm using the distribution found here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image. It is version 0.9.3. This explains why isodata would not be working but doesn't explain yen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `threshold_isodata` is only available in the master repo (i.e. not officially released in v0.9), hence the import error.

It turns out that `threshold_yen` wasn't properly imported into the `filter` subpackage in version 0.9. (This has been fixed in master.) Until v0.10 is released, you should import `threshold_yen` as follows:

```
from skimage.filter.thresholding import threshold_yen
```

**EDIT**: Note that this question and answer are specific to **very old versions** of scikit-image. The `skimage.filter` module was renamed `skimage.filters` in [v0.11](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api_changes.html#version-0-11)